# Can the different user event navigators on user profile pages be united?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface

I have always wondered why there are two different ways to navigate to user events/actions on the user profile page.

- There is a left navigation bar (on mobile, a dropdown list) with "Summary", "Answers", "Questions", etc.
- One of the dropdown items, "All Actions", brings up a row of buttons with a new list of event types, including "Comments".
- "Flags" isn't in either list. You have to know to click on "helpful flags" under "Impact".

I find myself needing to go to "Comments" often, as I don't always remember which post was commented on.  So, it's necessary to select "All Actions" from the dropdown, then "Comments" from the row of buttons.

**I think it would be easier for users if there were a *single* list of event categories to choose from.**

Failing this, "All Actions" could be renamed to "Other", since it doesn't show all types of actions, just a subset of the ones that aren't in the dropdown (although strangely, "Badges" appears in both).  I really do wish "Comments" was in the dropdown list.

Comment: If your feature-request is to remove some of those ways, I can't be in favour of it.

Comment: @Mast What do you mean? If the categories under "all actions" were moved in to the main list, what use would "all actions" be?

Comment: Note that there are 2 Comments sections; one is for viewing *your own* comments (from the All Actions tab) and the other is for viewing *responses* to your comments (from the Responses tab). Having them all under one tab, IMO, would it make it quite confusing.

Comment: @Justin Keeping the two categories separate is OK; it's just a matter of labeling. If we retain the "all" view (with all of the different actions merged in one list, but just add all of the left-nav things into it), they'd have to be labeled differently anyway.